# What's the best way to locally dim light sources in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

For example, on this image, how to best reduce the brightness of the lanterns on the temple ground without dimming the whole photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an Exposure Adjustment Layer reducing it to your taste

[image]

[image]

2. Inverse the Exposure Adjustment Layer's mask

[image]

3. Paint white onto the it where the darker exposure should be

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Sorry can't upvote,  my reputation doesn't allow it yet.